# Python Azure Function process file

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to use Youtube Data API in Python with Azure functions.
it works well locally. But in azure, I get 500 error.
It could be because of a problem with the processing of the file.

```
video = open('/tmp/v.' + vid_ext, 'wb+')
video.write(_video)`
```

create a video file with this, and use it at `mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('/tmp/v.' + vid_ext)`
To open `client_secret.json`, use file path

```
folderPath = 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = folerPath + 'client_secret.json'
```

Why is this code causing problem?
How can I fix it?
or any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is not helpful to solve this problem, you need to check the specific error of the azure function. You can use application insights to get the details error. The function must configure the corresponding application insights before you can view the log on the portal.

So you need to configure an application insights to your function app like this:

[image]

Then your function app will restart.

Of course, you can also go to kudu to view:

First, go to advanced tools, then click 'GO',

[image]

Then After you go to kudu, click Debug Console -> CMD -> LogFiles -> Application -> Functions -> yourtriggername. You will find log file there.

If you are based on linux OS, after go to kudu, just click 'log stream'(this is not supportted to consumption plan for linux.).

Answer (score 0):

I have already faced this problem, this is because FunctionApp is a read_only mod. You can not create a new file, you can not put data into the file in the FunctionApp. Once you will get enabled logging you will get the same error. Possible Solutions:-

1. You can put the file on Azure Blob and give the path of the blob to MediaFileUpload.
2. You can use Temp Folder writing access.